# config key may not be used with `rules`: except. Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following job in the pipeline, which I want to be run only on the master branch

```
docker:build-production:
  extends:
    - .docker:build
    - .aws-production-variables
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: never
```

but I get the following error:

```
jobs:docker:build-production config key may not be used with `rules`: except
```

I don't have the `except` keyword anywhere, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Edit:
For more context, it was failing because `docker:build-production:` job was inheriting from the `.docker:build` which had `except` clause in it. I should've used either `rules` or `only` and `except` in both of them for it to properly work.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the `extends` keyword, you reuse two configuration sections. These sections probably contain `only` and `except` keywords, which cannot be used together with `rules`. If you had control over them, you could transition them to use the `rules` keyword and stick with the extract you posted.

I have not found this in the official documentation, only in some discussions, as [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/run-pipeline-only-on-successful-merge-in-specific-branch/56551/4).

Answer (score 1):

I removed the rules clause and replaced it with only clause to run the job only on the master branch. Seems to be working.

```
docker:build-production:
  extends:
    - .docker:build
    - .aws-production-variables
  only:
    - master
```